# How to configure VS Code to compile/debug C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code

I've installed the C/C++ extension for VS Code but am not quite sure what I need to have in my `tasks.json` in order to compile a project. Is there an example I can look at somewhere?

Also, the extension refers to Clang tools, I kind of assumed that Clang doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: You can make a build.bat which calls cl with your intended parameters and then make a task which calls it via the scheme below, or you can make a task which calls cl directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a webpage where they explain more about the task.json file.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

The build tasks are project specific. To create a new project, open a directory in VSCode.

Following the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/tasks), press `Ctrl+Shift+P`, type `Configure Tasks`, select it and press `Enter`.

The tasks.json file will be opened. Paste the following build script into the file, and save it:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "make",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Makefile",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "always",
            // No args
            "args": ["all"],
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now go to `File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts` and add the following key binding for the build task:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { "key": "f8",          "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" }
]
```

Now when you press `F8` the Makefile will be executed and errors will be underlined in the editor.

Comment: I'm on Windows and *'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

Comment: I am not understanding what you are doing

Comment: I am trying to compile and run C++ application *on Windows*. Using MSVC.